# Angular 7 move the caret in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I'm developing a basic html editor and I need to add a `li` to an `ol` when the return get pressed.
I've managed to do it but every time I update the `innerhtml` in my `contenteditable` div the caret reset to the start position. I'd like to position the caret inside the newly created `li`. 
I've tried something like this but unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
setCursor() {
    let el, el2, range, sel;
    el = document.getElementById('editor');
    range = document.createRange();
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (el.childNodes.length > 0) {
      el2 = el.childNodes[el.childNodes.length - 1];
      range.setStartAfter(el2);
    } else {
      range.setStartAfter(el);
    }
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
```

I've also tried replacing

```
range.setStartAfter(el2);
```

with

```
range.setStart(el2,0);
```

but still nothing happens.

Does anybody have any idea to make it working?
Thanks.

Comment: try calling your `setCursor()` asynchroniously. for example `Promise.resoolve().then(() => this.setCursor())`. I think the html is not updated by the moment you are trying to set cursor

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work. Actually it doesn't work even if I add more elements to the list... so it should be an issue with the time the function is called.

Comment: Ok I guess I've solved the issue calling setCursor on the keyup event :-)